# How to match theoretical thread states and states showed by jvisualvm

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads, jvisualvm

If we will google something like 'java thread state' we will see approximately this diagram:

[image]

But if we will open jVisualVm we will see following:

[image]

Can you help to meatch these diagrams?

Sleeping state is just `Thread.sleep()`? Special case of the Running?

What the Park state?(I tried to google but I confused because I knew before only first diagram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram represents `java.lang.Thread.State` enum. [The Javadoc is quite helpful to get an understanding of the mapping you seek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html).

The JVisualVM state represent the extra state description you would see in a thread dump, e.g.:

```
 "Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x022f4000 nid=0xd14 in Object.wait() [0x044cf000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
```

So you could decipher the state on your own, if you get a thread dump and compare the state from JVisualVM and the thread dump by a thread name.

Here is the mapping you want:

- `Running` -> `java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE`
- `Sleeping` -> `java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)`
- `Wait` -> `java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)`
- `Park` -> `java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING TIMED_WAITING (parking)`
- `Monitor` -> `java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)`

The `Park` state is a special case of `WAITING` or `TIMED_WAITING`. The difference from `Wait` is that `Wait` happens on an object monitor (i.e. `Object.wait()` within a `synchronized` block). The `Park`, on the other hand, removes a thread from scheduling via `Unsafe.park` without any need of holding a monitor (i.e. it doesn't need a `synchronized` block).

Comment: Still unclear for me. TIMED_WAITING vs WAITING TIMED_WAITING for example. Parking?

Comment: You can check that in JavaDoc link I've added. `WAITING` - Thread state for a waiting thread. A thread is in the waiting state due to calling one of the following methods: Object.wait with no timeout, Thread.join with no timeout, LockSupport.park; `TIMED_WAITING` - Thread state for a waiting thread with a specified waiting time. A thread is in the timed waiting state due to calling one of the following methods with a specified positive waiting time: Thread.sleep, Object.wait with timeout, Thread.join with timeout, LockSupport.parkNanos, LockSupport.parkUntil

Comment: @gstackoverflow I've added clarification for `Park` as well

Comment: @gstackoverflow it means that the thread won't recieve any CPU time share from the thread scheduler - therefore it won't do anything, until it would be unparked. Here's an overview of that process: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071214/java-concurrency/java-101--understanding-java-threads--part-3--thread-scheduling-and-wait-notify.html

Answer (score 1):

park is

```
sun.misc.Unsafe.park()
```

Comment: can you extend your response? java doc is not obvious